# Can't use some functions from facebook instant game API

Tags: javascript, facebook-instant-games, cocoscreator

I am using facebook instant game SDK with cocos creator.

When I use method to recover player's name, ID, photo, it works very well.
However, when I try to recover a player's entry in a leaderboard, or their connected players, it just doesn't work.

I even copy-pasted the code from the SDK to check if something would work. Nothing does.

I test the game after uploading it on web, with my mobile. I also tried on Google Chrome, connected as a user test.

Does anyone know why I can use some SDK methods, but I can't use them all?
What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while now. No one has an idea to solve my problems ?